# I want my setTimeout function to restart when I immediately press it again during click

Tags: jquery, settimeout

So, I create a animation of letters appearing one by one ever 25 milliseconds to complete the Sentence, but whenever I click button and the sentence is not finish, the missing letters overlaps the another sentence.

It was supposed to be 'Agree to Terms and Policies"
the other sentence is 'You've agreed to our terms and Policies', but I clicked the button while it just completed "You've agreed to our terms", so the remaining letters on "and Policies" are added on the "Agree to our Terms and Policies" and become like that.
Just like this:

[image]
  HTML

```
<div class ="d-flex mb-4 my-2">
                        <div class = "d-flex mr-3">
                            <div class = "checkmark" style="position:relative; background: black; width:2.5em; transform: scale(.7);">
                                <div class = "checkmark2"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <p class = "mb-0 p1">Agree to Terms and Policies</p>
                        <p class = "mb-0 p2" style="display:none"></p>
                    </div>
JQUERY:

var showText = function (target, message, index, interval) {    
                  if (index < message.length) { 
                    $(target).append(message[index++]); 
                    setTimeout(function(){showText(target, message, index, interval);},interval); 
                  } 
                }


$('.signupmodalborder .checkmark2').click(function(){

    if(checkbox == 0)
    {
        checkbox++;
        $('.signupmodalborder .checkmark2').css({"background":"#f1c500"});
        $('.signupmodalborder .checkmark2').append("<style> .signupmodalborder .checkmark2:after{background: #f1c500}</style>");
        $('.signupmodalborder .checkmark2').append("<style> .signupmodalborder .checkmark2:before{background: #f1c500}</style>");
        $('.signupmodalborder').find('p').text("");
        $('.signupmodalborder p').css({"font-weight":"bold"});
        $(function () { 

            showText(".signupmodalborder p", "You've agreed to our Terms and Policies",0, 25);    

        }); 
        clearTimeout(showText);

    }
    else
    {

        checkbox = 0;
        $('.signupmodalborder .checkmark2').css({"background":"white"});
        $('.signupmodalborder .checkmark2').append("<style> .signupmodalborder .checkmark2:after{background: white}</style>");
        $('.signupmodalborder .checkmark2').append("<style> .signupmodalborder .checkmark2:before{background: white}</style>");
        $('.signupmodalborder').find('p').text("");
        $('.signupmodalborder p').css({"font-weight":"normal"});
        $(function () { 

            showText(".signupmodalborder p", "Agree to our Terms and Policies", 0, 25);    

        });
    }

});
```

Comment: Think you could add some HTML or simplify the JavaScript so we could see an example? Also, where and how is `showText` defined?

Comment: Oh sorry, I've edited the codes.